# Segmenting a df based on condition shows nan values in jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Using `df[columns][df[colums]<0.5]` to segment a DataFrame in Pandas usually only showed me the rows matching this condition.

Just recently I end up getting NaN - Values shown:

[image]

Was there an update I'm missing or what is causing this behaviour usually?

Dropping all NaN with `.dropna()` is obviously a fast solution to this issue, but doesn't explain the change in "behaviour".

**Fix: Don't put columns in double brackets..**

Comment: What about `df.loc[df[colums]<0.5, columns]`? Even if this isn't the fix, it's the canonical syntax so I recommend you adopt it for readability.

Comment: Have you checked if there were NaN values in `"district-heating"` and `"id"` before slicing? What does `df.loc[[0,1,2], ["id",  "district-heating"]]` return?

Comment: @Dan no nan values and df.loc[..] returns the expected values.

Comment: I might have been because of your double brackets around `"district-heating"` as that returns a dataframe instead of a series. i.e. don't do `test[["district-heating"]] < 0.1` but rather `test["district-heating"] < 0.1`. Of course, either way you should certainly be using `.loc`

Comment: @Dab you are correct this solves the issue. I had to have done this mistake just by chance this whole day. Without noticing. Time for a break.Why is .loc better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need compare by one column and filter by multiple columns use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df['district-heating'] < 0.5, ['id','district-heating']]
```

Comment: For some reason this gives me an arrow not finding "district-heating"

Comment: @Phil - What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: Fixed it. Might you explain why .loc is better than the way I'm doing it? Readability?

Comment: @Phil - 2 operation in one - readability and I think performance should be better, if many columns.